# Can there be a homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ that maps $\mathbb Q$ to the dyadic rationals?

Tags: general-topology

Can there be a homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ to itself that maps $\mathbb Q$ to the dyadic rationals?

What I know is that homeomorphisms of $[0,1]$ have to be increasing or decreasing and map endpoints to endpoints.  I see there is a certain struction to the dyadic rationals which $\mathbb Q$ doesn't have but I can't see if that's a problem or not.

Comment: Look up "Minkowski Question Mark function."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $Q=\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ and $D$ be the set of dyadic rationals in $[0,1]$. $Q$ and $D$ are countable dense linear orders with endpoints, so they are order-isomorphic. Let $h:Q\to D$ be an order-isomorphism. $[0,1]$ is the Dedekind completion of each of these sets, so $h$ extends to an autohomeomorphism of $[0,1]$

Comment: So there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ such homeomorphisms!

Answer (score 0):

For the curious, here's an "algorithm" that prints $h(x)$ bit by bit for $0\le x<1$:

1. print "0."
2. Set $(a,b,c,d)\leftarrow(0,1,1,1)$ *(Now $\frac ab\le x<\frac cd$)*
3. If $x=\frac ab$, terminate *($x$ was rational and we have produced a terminating dyadic)*
4. Set $(u,v)\leftarrow(a+c,b+d)$
5. If $x<\frac uv$, print "0" and set $(c,d)\leftarrow (u,v)$. Otherwise print "1" and set $(a,b)\leftarrow (u,v)$
6. Go back to step 3.

(It is not an algorithm because for irrational $x$ it will run endlessly, producing an endless bit sequence)